# How to push an entire array in javascript based on conditional content of single array element?

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script

I have created a Google script that pushes data every hour from the Capital Bikeshare API to a Google Sheet, but I have noticed that the way I am currently pulling the data doesn't maintain consistency over time. Here's the code I'm using:

```
function myFunction() {
  // Set the active spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var currentData = ss.getSheetByName("Current");
  var historicData = ss.getSheetByName("Historic");  
  
  // Fetch API
  var stationInfo = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://gbfs.capitalbikeshare.com/gbfs/en/station_information.json');
  var stationStatus = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://gbfs.capitalbikeshare.com/gbfs/en/station_status.json');
  
  // Get the current date and time
var today = new Date();
var date = today.getFullYear()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getDate();
var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
var dateTime = date+' '+time;
  
  // Parse the JSON reply
  var jsonInfo = stationInfo.getContentText();
  var dataInfo = JSON.parse(jsonInfo); 
  var jsonStatus = stationStatus.getContentText();
  var dataStatus = JSON.parse(jsonStatus); 
  
  // Create the data frame for every BID station
  var stationInfo72 = dataInfo["data"]["stations"][69];
  var stationStatus72 = dataStatus["data"]["stations"][69];
  
  var stationInfo87 = dataInfo["data"]["stations"][83];
  var stationStatus87 = dataStatus["data"]["stations"][83];
  
  var stationInfo330 = dataInfo["data"]["stations"][311];
  var stationStatus330 = dataStatus["data"]["stations"][311];
  
  var stationInfo153 = dataInfo["data"]["stations"][143];
  var stationStatus153 = dataStatus["data"]["stations"][143];
  
  var stationInfo226 = dataInfo["data"]["stations"][213];
  var stationStatus226 = dataStatus["data"]["stations"][213];
  
  var stationInfo365 = dataInfo["data"]["stations"][342];
  var stationStatus365 = dataStatus["data"]["stations"][342];
  
  var stationInfo473 = dataInfo["data"]["stations"][446];
  var stationStatus473 = dataStatus["data"]["stations"][446];
    
  var outputStationsInfo = [stationInfo72, stationInfo87, stationInfo330, stationInfo153, stationInfo226, stationInfo365, stationInfo473]
  var outputStationsStatus = [stationStatus72, stationStatus87, stationStatus330, stationStatus153, stationStatus226, stationStatus365, stationStatus473]
  Logger.log(outputStationsInfo, outputStationsStatus)
 
  // Create lists of each element
  var outputHead = [];
  var outputTail = [];
  
    outputStationsInfo.forEach(function(elem,i) {
    outputHead.push([elem["station_id"],elem["name"],elem["capacity"], elem["lat"], elem["lon"]]);
  });
  
  outputStationsStatus.forEach(function(elem,i) {
    outputTail.push([elem["num_bikes_available"], elem["num_ebikes_available"], dateTime]);
  });
  

  // Publish arrays in the Current sheet
currentData.getRange(2,1,7,5).setValues(outputHead);
currentData.getRange(2,6,7,3).setValues(outputTail);

  
  // Publish arrays in the Historic sheet
historicData.getRange(historicData.getLastRow() + 1,1,7,5).setValues(outputHead);
historicData.getRange(historicData.getLastRow() - 6,6,7,3).setValues(outputTail);
  
}
```

Essentially, I am drilling into the 69th item in the indexes of the JSONs to get the data that I need from two different APIs, and then I merge them together to create a data frame of everything I need to push to the sheet. However, sometimes the API does not report them in the normal order and I end up getting bikeshare stations that aren't in my study area. For example, 99% of the time the 69th item in the array is station_id = 72, but occasionally it's station_id = 73 or something.

Is there a way to conditionally pull a specific array based on the station_id number within the array? I feel like the answer might allow me to do a loop as well to clean this up. Any advice is helpful, as I'm super new to this.

Comment: btw, dot notation, like `dataInfo.data.stations[69]` for objects increase readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Conditionally picking elements: filter

For conditionally picking elements from an array in JavaScript, [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) should always be a consideration.

Create a predicate function that matches the shape of your data and checks for certain station IDs.

Here is a function that returns a predicate function.  You put in the IDs you want in an array, and it returns the required function for `filter`.

```js
function byStationId(stationIds) {
  return function (obj) {
    return stationIds.indexOf(obj.station_id) > -1;
  };
}

var myStationFilter = byStationId([72, 73, 74]);
var outputStationsInfo = dataInfo.data.stations.filter(myStationFilter);
```

#### Transforming data: map

The pattern

```js
var newArray = [];
oldArray.forEach(function (item) {
  newArray.push(/* something based on item */);
});
```

can usually be replaced with [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
var newArray = oldArray.map(function (item) { return /* something based on item */});
```

Think of this as the "adapter" from one data shape to another.

```js
function cleanInfo(info) {
  return [info.station_id, info.name, info.capacity, info.lat, info.lon];
}
var outputHead = outputStationsInfo.map(cleanInfo);
```

For the `dateTime` injection, just do the same trick demonstrated above with the station IDs: have a function that takes a date string and returns the appropriate adapter function.

(Also note the provided date formatting utility Apps Scripts provides, [`Utilities.formatDate()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate,-timezone,-format))

```js
var dateTime = Utilities.formatDate(
  new Date(),
  ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(),
  "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
);

function cleanStatus(dateTime) {
  return function (status) {
    return [status.num_bikes_available, status.num_bikes_available, dateTime];
  };
}

var outputTail = outputStationsStatus.map(cleanStatus(dateTime));
```

Here's everything together, *untested, just for inspiration*.  You must at the very least update the line with the station IDs to match **your** desired station IDs.  Note that the helper functions for `map` and `filter` are at the bottom, taking advantage of JavaScript's [hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting) feature.

```js
function myFunction() {
  // Set the active spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // Get the current date and time
  var dateTime = Utilities.formatDate(
    new Date(),
    ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(),
    "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
  );

  // Fetch API
  var stationInfo = UrlFetchApp.fetch(
    "https://gbfs.capitalbikeshare.com/gbfs/en/station_information.json"
  );
  var stationStatus = UrlFetchApp.fetch(
    "https://gbfs.capitalbikeshare.com/gbfs/en/station_status.json"
  );
  // Parse the JSON reply
  var dataInfo = JSON.parse(stationInfo.getContentText());
  var dataStatus = JSON.parse(stationStatus.getContentText());

  // Create the data frame for every BID station
  var myStationFilter = byStationId([72, 73, 74]); //!! UPDATE THESE NUMBERS
  var outputStationsInfo = dataInfo.data.stations.filter(myStationFilter);
  var outputStationsStatus = dataStatus.data.station.filter(myStationFilter);

  // Create lists of each element
  var outputHead = outputStationsInfo.map(cleanInfo);
  var outputTail = outputStationsStatus.map(cleanStatus(dateTime));

  // Publish arrays in the Current sheet
  var currentData = ss.getSheetByName("Current");
  currentData.getRange(2, 1, 7, 5).setValues(outputHead);
  currentData.getRange(2, 6, 7, 3).setValues(outputTail);

  // Publish arrays in the Historic sheet
  var historicData = ss.getSheetByName("Historic");
  historicData
    .getRange(historicData.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 7, 5)
    .setValues(outputHead);
  historicData
    .getRange(historicData.getLastRow() - 6, 6, 7, 3)
    .setValues(outputTail);

  //-------- helper functions ------------

  function byStationId(stationIds) {
    return function (obj) {
      return stationIds.indexOf(obj.station_id) > -1;
    };
  }

  function cleanInfo(info) {
    return [info.station_id, info.name, info.capacity, info.lat, info.lon];
  }

  function cleanStatus(dateTime) {
    return function (status) {
      return [status.num_bikes_available, status.num_bikes_available, dateTime];
    };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to check if the element's `station_id` is as expected. If not, check through the surrounding parts of the array using [a custom iterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators).

#### Snippet:

```
/**
 * @return indexes of the surrounding ``i`` in batches of 5
 */
function* checkSurroundings(i, lastIndex) {
  let j = i;
  function* check(ct, border, reverse = true, limit = border < 5 ? border : 5) {
    const margin = reverse ? ct - limit : ct + limit;
    while (ct - margin !== 0) yield reverse ? --ct : ++ct;
    return ct;
  }
  while (i !== 0 || j < lastIndex) {
    if (i !== 0) i = yield* check(i, i);
    if (j < lastIndex) j = yield* check(j, lastIndex - j, false);
    //console.log({ i, j });
  }
}



var stations = dataInfo["data"]["stations"];
var stationInfo72 = stations[69];
const iter = checkSurroundings(69,stations.length-1)
//if station_id is not 72, loop through the surrounding indexes
while(stationInfo72["station_id"] !== 72){
  const next = iter.next();
  if(next.done) {
    console.error("station id 72 not found");
    break;
  }
  stationInfo72 = stations[next.value]
}
```

Snippet showing how `checkSurroundings` iterates:

```js
/**
 * @return indexes of the surrounding ``i`` in batches of 5
 */
function* checkSurroundings(i, lastIndex) {
  let j = i;
  function* check(ct, border, reverse = true, limit = border < 5 ? border : 5) {
    const margin = reverse ? ct - limit : ct + limit;
    while (ct - margin !== 0) yield reverse ? --ct : ++ct;
    return ct;
  }
  while (i !== 0 || j < lastIndex) {
    if (i !== 0) i = yield* check(i, i);
    if (j < lastIndex) j = yield* check(j, lastIndex - j, false);
    console.log({ i, j });
  }
}

console.log("Order of iteration",[...checkSurroundings(50, 100)])
```